# How to customize the default error message "The value '' is invalid" for dynamically generated form

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net core. I have a form which is generated dynamically. I want the validation error message to be `"The value must be numeric"` instead I get

```
"The value 'a' is invalid."
```

Here is my View Model:

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The value must be numeric")]
public List<int> Units_Service { get; set; }
```

Here is my form code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Workload_Category_Name.Count; i++)
{
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
           <b><u>  @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Workload_Category_Name[i])</u> </b>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
          @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Units_Service[i], new { style = "width: 15%", MaskedTextBox = "9999" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Units_Service[i])
       </div>
   </div>
 }
```

Despite the fact, I have put the custom error message in my View Model as shown above, I keep getting the default message `"The value '' is invalid"`. Please what is the solution to this kind of scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the model binding fails before your Regex gets a chance to do its stuff.  The model binder is throwing the error that you see.

Try changing the property to a list of `string` and then convert back to integers when needed.

```
[RegularExpression("^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "The value must be numeric")]
public List<string> Units_Service { get; set; }


List<int> convertedToInts = _model.Units_Service.Select(v => int.Parse(v)).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi @Neil W, thanks for your answer. I have tried your approach but I always get `The value must be numeric` error message even when I put numeric values in the form.  It is failing now for every case. Here is an example of the form field when I inspect on the browser `<input maskedtextbox="9999" id="Units_Service_1_" name="Units_Service[1]" style="width: 15%" type="text" value="2">`